# Readyboost v Disk cache

Tags: windows, diskcache

I am considering buying a new laptop and have noticed a number of the mid range offerings have 8Gb cache with the 1Tb disk. I wondered if anyone has experience of the benefit of this configuration and also whether just adding an appropriate amount of 'Readyboost' memory would achieve the same thing (its cheaper!)

Answer (score 1):

Readyboost is used when the free RAM available is less. Readyboost is not a replacement for RAM. Readyboost is used with flash drives as they are bit faster than Physical Drives. Since flash drives cannot match the speeds of RAM, you cannot depend on Readyboost for fast processing.